# Wrong password in Terminal

Tags: command-line, downloaders

I'm new in Ubuntu's world and I have a quick question (hope it doesn't repeat): I want to download some restricted files for watching movies online but there's a problem, it wants to introduce a password....now my question is..what password? the administrative one...or?

P.S Sorry for my bad english

Have a nice weekend!

Comment: To be certain, can you post a screenshot of the password prompt?

Comment: What exactly are you doing and what are you hoping to achieve through it? As it stands, nobody can accurately tell what kind of password prompt you're talking about. Please [edit] your question to add or clarify things.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like it wants superuser access, also known as "root" access.  In Ubuntu the normal way to gain superuser access is via `sudo` which is a way of using your own user account to gain superuser access.  In this case, the password it wants will be your own account password.

Note: It pays to be suspicious of anything that claims to require your password or superuser access. You need to be sure that you absolutely trust the company whose software is requesting this.

Comment: Thank you! Is there anyway that I can skip this "superuser access"?

Comment: Without knowing what it is you're installing I don't know.

Comment: Ok...then what application should I install to watch movies(etc) online?

Comment: What movies?  What format? Where from?  You should include more information in the original question, if you would like people to recommend alternative solutions.